# Convert binary data file generated in windows to linux

Tags: c, windows, linux, binary, data-conversion

I apologize ahead of time for my lack of c knowledge, as I am a native FORTRAN programmer.  I was given some c code to debug which ingests a binary file and parses it into an input file containing several hundred records (871, to be exact) for a Fortran program that I'm working with.  The problem is that these input binaries, and the associated c code, were created in a Windows environment.  The parser reads through the binary until it reaches the end of the file:

```
SAGE_Lvl0_Packet GetNextPacket()
{     

   int i;
   SAGE_Lvl0_Packet  inpkt;
   WORD              rdbuf[128]; 
   memset(rdbuf,0,sizeof(rdbuf));
   fprintf(stdout,"Nbytes: %u\n",Nbytes);//returns 224
   if((i = fread(rdbuf,Nbytes,1,Fp)) != 1)
      FileEnd = 1;
   else      
    {         
       if(FileType == 0)
          memcpy(&(inpkt.CCSDS),rdbuf,Nbytes);                 
       else  
          memcpy(&inpkt,rdbuf,Nbytes);
       memcpy(&CurrentPacket,&inpkt,sizeof(inpkt));
    }
    return inpkt;
}
```

So when the code gets to packet 872, this snippet should return FileEnd = 1.  Instead, the parser attempts to read a large amount of data from (near) the end of the file.  This, I would think, would cause the program to crash (at least it would in Fortran.  Would c just start reading the next portion of memory?)  Fortunately, there is a CRC later on in the code that catches that the parser isn't reading correct data and exits gracefully.

I assume the problem originates with the binary buffer size and value in a Windows binary being larger/different than that in Linux.  If that is the case, is there an easy way to convert Windows' binaries to Linux either in c or Linux?  If I'm wrong in my assumption, then perhaps I need to look over the code some more.  BTW, a WORD is an unsigned short int, and a SAGE_Lvl0_Packet is a 3-tiered structure with a total of 106 WORDs.

Comment: Very, very short answer: feof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest problem here is that, when `fread()` indicates end of file, the `FileEnd` flag gets set, but the function still ends up returning an (invalid) zeroed-out packet. Not a particularly robust design. I assume that the caller should be checking `FileEnd` before it attempts to use the packet just returned, but since that's not shown, it's quite possible that's a false assumption.

Also, not knowing what the packet looks like, it's impossible to tell whether the various `memcpy()` calls are correct. The fact that `memcpy()` is asked to copy 224 bytes into a structure that is supposedly only 212 bytes long is highly problematic.

There are likely other issues, but those are the big ones I see at the moment.

Comment: I may be wrong on the actual size of the packet.  I say this because there are 4 words defined as (for instance) WORD PacketType : 10.  I presumed this to mean that PacketType is only 10 bits long, but perhaps PacketType still takes up a 16 bit block of memory.

Comment: And I apologize for not posting the rest of the code - I know that can be frustrating - but this is code that goes along with controlling a satellite, so I don't want to post too much of it up here.